# What is the HL7 ZDS segment used for?

Tags: hl7

My very old HL7 parser has just hit a snag as it is now getting some messages with a ZDS segment present.  It was easy to fix by adding a ZDS object to my parser, but I am trying to find out what it is used for.  Googling hasn't helped much.  This is a sample

```
ZDS|PERFORM|p0001236^PATEL^ATEST^^^^^^HHB_INOP_PRSNL^^^^OTHER|20100714101800|CD:653
ZDS|TRANSCRIBE|p0001236^PATEL^ATEST^^^^^^HHB_INOP_PRSNL^^^^OTHER|20100714101800|CD:653
ZDS|SIGN|p0001236^PATEL^ATEST^^^^^^HHB_INOP_PRSNL^^^^OTHER|20100714101912|CD:653
```

So, I'm interested in what each field is though looking at this sample data, it seems I don't lose much by just dropping the whole segment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In HL7, [all segments that begin with the letter Z are considered to be custom](http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-z-segments) and are not defined further by the HL7 standard.  You will need to find out what system is responsible for generating these ZDS segments and ask the owners of that system to provide you their specification.

Comment: The Cerner tech got back to me and said that although they do use this segment, I can just drop them!  :)

Comment: I don't think anything critical to the lab result is in the ZDS, but there is information that might be something a doc wants to see...i.e. Who signed the document and when, who transcribed it and when, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As Scott said, "Z" segments are custom and can vary from vendor to vendor.  In the Cerner realm, however, ZDS segments are typically used for "Document Succession" purposes -- a means of document version tracking and synchronization between two supportive systems.

Answer (score 1):

The ZDS segment is used to communicate document endorsement information (actions done or to be done) in Unsolicited Document Results. only a specific solution of Millennium use it, so if you don't need just ignore it.